# Where does the human brain drain to?

Tags: human-anatomy, brain, blood-circulation

When a brain has a aneurysm and the patient survives untreated then   where does that blood drain to or how is it absorbed? How is the pain perceived?

Comment: if you mean the pain in brain during the operation, It doesnt, because there is no nocireceptors in brain. I actually doubt about the aneyrysm survivel without threatmeant, and i hope someone is going to answer that part soon.